# How to show the following inequality in Measure Theory

Tags: integration, measure-theory

How to show the following inequality in Measure Theory:

> If $f$ is a non-negative measurable function defined on a measurable set $E$ then for any $\lambda >0$ we have $m\{x\in E:f(x)>\lambda \}\le\frac{1}{\lambda}\int _E f$ where $m$ denotes measure of a set

I can't figure out how to approach the above problem.Please give some hints.

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be less than a number? I think I'm confused by your question

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I undid the bad..

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $A:=\{x\in E\mid f(x)>\lambda\}$ and note that $\lambda1_A< f1_A$.

What happens if you integrate on both sides?